# Why is __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ called that?

Tags: c++, objective-c, gcc, gnu

I see `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` used a lot in answers to questions on this site, and I understand the usefulness of this function, but why is it called `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`?  It's not an ugly function, but it's not exactly pretty either.

Comment: As the docs say, "in C++, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` contains the type signature of the function as well as its bare name".  I guess whoever implemented this compiler feature decided that those names were prettier than the bare function names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is called `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` because it is a "decorated" `__FUNCTION__` (at least in C++, in C they are both equivalent). In C++, the return type and the parameters type are also displayed.

Note that both `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and `__FUNCTION__` are not C but GNU C. `__func__` is C.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably derived from the expression "pretty-print", meaning stylistic formatting of plain-text files such as program source.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint

Answer (score 1):

This is a construct within the GCC that outputs the type signature of the function in C++, and is synonymous with `__func__` in C:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html